# How to determine if a DBIx::Class::Row has a relationship already fetched?

Tags: dbix-class

Here's my situation: we have master tables with relationships to attribute tables. Sometimes, we fetch a row all by itself:

```
my $row = $rs->search({ some_key => 'some_value' })->first;
```

and sometimes we join one or more tables:

```
my $row = $rs->search({ some_key => 'some_value' }, { join => 'attributes' });
```

We have "helper" methods that look up specific attributes:

```
sub get_x_attr {
  my $obj = shift;
  my $x_attr = $obj->attributes->search({ attribute_name => 'x' })->one_row;
  return $x_attr ? $x_attr->attribute_value : 'default';
}
```

This seems to issue another query, and while it's a pretty low-impact query, these add up when you are doing that zillions of times a day.

Now, if the row was joined originally, I could write the helper as:

```
my @attrs = grep { $_->attribute_name eq 'x' } $obj->attributes->all;
my $x_attribute = $attrs[0] || return 'default';
# etc.
```

and there'd be no additional query.

Here's my question: is there a safe, reliable way to interrogate "$obj" to see if it's got attributes pre-fetched? And further, is there any way to tell after the fact if the join was conditional (e.g., 'WHERE attribute_name = 'some_other_value', which would make $obj->attributes rather useless here)?

(I did some digging, and found that $obj->{internals}{related_resultsets} has the answer to the first question, but since it's not part of the exposed API, I'm very much opposed to using it this way.)

Comment: you should use find and specify the key instead of search->first

Comment: Agreed, but that doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score -1):

Use the relationship methods, if the relationship is prefetched the cached related row is used, if not a query is automatically executed.

Note that joining won't populate the cache, only prefetch does.

Search will always issue a query and never restrict the resultset via Perl code like your grep example.

Comment: Yeah, that's problematic. If the relationship would return many rows, then you end up with a fallback that is worse than a filtered query might be.

What I'm looking for is some way to interrogate the original $row object to see if it has a specific relationship pre-fetched. If it does, I am OK assuming that the prefetch has every row of potential interest (although in degenerate cases it may have filtered those, I understand).